# How to add a layout below a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to add a Relative Layout below a TextView and above a Button. My buttons are in a LinearLayout and the parent is a RelativeLayout.

Here is My code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iWantPageLogo"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wic_logo_small" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goButton_iWant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/go" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteTextView_iWant"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/goButton_iWant"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iWantPageLogo"
        android:hint="@string/search" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iWantLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/iWantPageLogo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/iWant"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:="@+id/iWantLabel">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iNeedToBuy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/iWantPageLogo"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/iNeedToBuy"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/iNeedToBuyEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/iNeedToBuy"
            android:hint="@string/product"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/feedButton_feed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/feed"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/iWantButton_feed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/iwant"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareButton_feed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/share"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profileButton_feed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/profile"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Relative Layout(which contains TextView and EditText) which is in the parent layout(RelativeLayout) to be below iWantLabel and above the Linear Layout which contains buttons. How to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you pretty much know everything and need just a little attention.
1) you need to mention the place of all your layouts relative to other views as below or above. because some of their hight is fill_parrent which causes problems (overlapping the others) when the place is not mentioned clearly
2) you need to give an id to your linear layout
3) you need to set the place of your relative layout using layout_below and layout_above